# guava eventbus post after transaction/commit

Tags: spring, guava, event-bus

I am currently playing around with guava's eventbus in spring and while the general functionality is working fine so far i came across the following problem:

When a user want's to change data on a "Line" entity this is handled as usual in a backend service. In this service the data will be persisted via JPA first and after that I create a "NotificationEvent" with a reference to the changed entity. Via the EventBus I send the reference of the line to all subscribers.

```
public void notifyUI(String lineId) {
    EventBus eventBus = getClientEventBus();
    eventBus.post(new LineNotificationEvent(lineId));
}
```

the eventbus itself is created simply using new EventBus() in the background.

now in this case my subscribers are on the frontend side, outside of the @Transactional realm. so when I change my data, post the event and let the subscribers get all necessary updates from the database the actual transaction is not committed yet, which makes the subscribers fetch the old data.

the only quick fix i can think of is handling it asynchronously and wait for a second or two. But is there another way to post the events using guava AFTER the transaction has been committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think guava is "aware" of spring at all, and in particular not with its "@Transactional" stuff.

So you need a creative solution here. One solution I can think about is to move this code to the place where you're sure that the transaction has finished.
One way to achieve that is using `TransactionSyncrhonizationManager`:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization(){
           void afterCommit(){
                // do what you want to do after commit
                // in this case call the notifyUI method
           }
});
```

Note, that if the transaction fails (rolls back) the method won't be called, in this case you'll probably need `afterCompletion` method. See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.html)

Another possible approach is refactoring your application to something like this:

```
@Service
public class NonTransactionalService {

   @Autowired 
   private ExistingService existing;

   public void entryPoint() {

      String lineId = existing.invokeInTransaction(...);
      // now you know for sure that the transaction has been committed
      notifyUI(lineId);
   }
}

@Service
public class ExistingService  {

   @Transactional
   public String invokeInTransaction(...) {
      // do your stuff that you've done before
   }
}
```

One last thing I would like to mention here, is that Spring itself provides an events mechanism, that you might use instead of guava's one.

See [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) for example

Comment: hey thanks for your solution, i was thinking about the latter as well, just in a different way though. i will see which one suits me better. i also read about spring's eventbus implementation and during my short research i couldn't figure out how i could create a custom scope, since my application has different clients that need to be separated quite strictly. using guava i could do it quite easily in a factory object.